# Quick Analysis of best possible move in this board

Tags: analysis, tactics

What's black's best possible move and why?

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "r3k3/pp2b3/1qn1Np2/2p1p2Q/4P2p/1NP4P/PP3Pr1/2KR4 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Have you noticed that black has only one legal move? If you hadn't noticed that, you should consider the position longer on your own before asking here. If you had noticed that, your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's black's best possible move and why?

Unfortunately, Black will lose this game. His king is indeed in check, but he can postpone mate only with `1...Rg6`. The problem with Black's position is that king has no viable retreat:

1. He can't go to `d-file` as he would be in check from rook on `d1`;
2. He can't go to `f8` because he would be in check from knight on `e6`;
3. He can't go to `e7` as Black bishop stands there;
4. He can't go to `f7` because White queen controls that square so he would be again in check;

After `1...Rg6` White plays `Qxg6` and gives checkmate:

```
[Title "White mates after Rg6"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "r3k3/pp2b3/1qn1Np2/2p1p2Q/4P2p/1NP4P/PP3Pr1/2KR4 b - - 0 1"] 

1...Rg6 2.Qg6# 1-0
```